# How to zip multiple files in a folder by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, zip, zip.js

I have been reading question posted, however i could not find reasonable answers.

What I want to do is zip selected files. The file are all pdf files. 
Here is html my code

```
<form role="form" id="download">
    <div id="all-folders-1" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input name="pdfs" class="select pull-left" value="first.pdf" type="checkbox" style="margin-right:5px;"><b class="pull-left">Folder</b>
        <br/>
        <div class="all-folders-checkbox checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="pdfs" class="entity" value="file1.pdf" type="checkbox">
                File 1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="all-folders-checkbox  checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="pdfs" class="entity" value="file2.pdf" type="checkbox">
                File 2
           </label>
        </div>
        <div class="all-folders-checkbox  checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="pdfs" class="entity" value="file3.pdf" type="checkbox">
                File 3
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="all-folders-checkbox checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="pdfs" class="entity" value="file4.pdf" type="checkbox">
                File 4
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here I get selected checkbox by jquery.

```
var selected = [];
$('#download div input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Basically I want to save each value `.pdf` in an array named `selected`. After that I dont know how to zip them in a folder by javascript. Or is that possible?

Comment: take a look at this library: http://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: Not really sure, there are implentations of pkzip in javascript, but I'd guess what you're trying to do isn't possible, or at least very complicated, and that you generally shouldn't do this with javascript etc.

Comment: I have seen that library while searching, but couldnt decide how to use it in my project. I think that I should write additional javascript code to get the files from the array consisting of the files name which will be compressed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to download selected files in your browser, create a zip and give the zip file to the user. You can take a look at http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/downloader.html . This example uses JSZip but you should be able to adapt it to any javascript library.